# Errors: "expression must have class type" & "left of must have class/struct/union"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I have a program I'm making to calculate the area of a rectangle using measurements specified by the user. I'm using a class to do this for specific reasons, but my compiler generates two errors...

- `expression must have class type`
- `left of '.getArea' must have class/struct/union`

How do I fix this?

**Rectangle.h**

```
class Rectangle
{
private:
  int length;
  int width;
  int area = length * width;

public:
  Rectangle(int l, int w);
  int getLength();
  void setLength(int l);
  int getWidth();
  void setWidth(int w);
  int getArea();
  void setArea(int a);
};
```

**Rectangle.cpp**

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(int l, int w)
{
   length = l;
   width = w;
}
--some code--
int Rectangle::getArea()
{
   return area;
}
void Rectangle::setArea(int a)
{
   area = a;
}
```

**Area.cpp**

```
int i, lth, wth;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter your measurements, length first" << endl;
    cin >> lth >> wth;
    Rectangle rMeasure(int lth, int wth);
    cout << "Area of this rectangle is: " << rMeasure.getArea(); //problem code
}
```

Comment: `int area = length * width;` That's not how it works.

Comment: `Rectangle rMeasure(int lth, int wth);` is a function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
Rectangle rMeasure(int lth, int wth);
```

is a function declaration.

It seems you mean

```
Rectangle rMeasure(lth, wth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Few changes in your code is required

1.

```
private:
    int length;
    int width;
    int area;
```

2.

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(int l, int w)
{
    length = l;
    width = w;
    this->area=length * width;
}
```

3.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter your measurements, length first" << endl;
    cin >> lth >> wth;
    Rectangle rMeasure(lth, wth);
    cout << "Area of this rectangle is: " << rMeasure.getArea();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=72d4a2f46ce5a4a7)